# Set Print Area - OpenXML with Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml

Does anybody know how to set print area through OpenXML SDK in Excel?

I've tried using the following code:

```
public void XLUpdateDefinedName(string fileName, string definedName, string newRange)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true))
    {
        WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;

        var definedNames = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<DefinedNames>().FirstOrDefault();
        DefinedName name = definedNames.Descendants<DefinedName>().Where(m => m.Name == definedName).Single();
        UInt32Value locSheetId = name.LocalSheetId;
        name = null;//.Remove();
        wbPart.Workbook.Save();
        name = new DefinedName() { Name = definedName, LocalSheetId = locSheetId , Text = newRange}
            ;
        wbPart.Workbook.Save();
        //newDefinedName.Text = newRange;
        //definedNames.Append(newDefinedName);

    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I continue to receive an error from excel saying there is unreadable content in file with the following code.

```
   public void XLUpdateDefinedName(string fileName, string definedName, string newRange, string sheet, UInt32Value localId)
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true))
        {                
            String sheetName = sheet;
            string topLeft = newRange.Split(':').First();
            string bottomRight = newRange.Split(':').Last();
            WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;

            var definedNames = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<DefinedNames>().FirstOrDefault();
            var nameCollection = definedNames.Descendants<DefinedName>().Where(m => m.Text.StartsWith(sheetName));
            DefinedName name = nameCollection.Count() > 0 ? nameCollection.First() : null;
            UInt32Value locSheetId;
            if (name != null)
            {
                locSheetId = name.LocalSheetId;
                name.Remove();
                wbPart.Workbook.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                locSheetId = localId;
            }
            name = new DefinedName() { Name = "_xlnm.Print_Area", LocalSheetId = locSheetId};
            name.Text = String.Format("{0}!{1}:{2}", sheetName,topLeft,bottomRight);
            definedNames.Append(name);
            wbPart.Workbook.Save();
        }}
```

newRange is of the form ( $A$10:$C$15 )

Comment: try this link it may or may not help.. make sure to look at the entire page it provides examples.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc540662(office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but actually found that, and it uses VB Automation for setting print area.  I need to maintain a print area on a worksheet that I am copying into a new workbook, and I would like to accomplish it using OpenXml if possible to keep my application consistent.

Comment: if it's done using vb automation why not use OleAutomation better known as Interop or Com-Interop that is if you are coding in C#

Comment: My current task involves removing an Excel add-in's dependence on Com-Interop.  My company uses a custom calculation engine on top of Excel, and using interop causes Excel to fire off calculations that really are unnecessary.  The end result is a simple tool that takes a really long to complete a relatively simple task. By removing interop, I can manipulate an excel document through OpenXml, and do one calculation at the end of all changes to that document, which, in turn, significantly reduces the time to complete the task.

Comment: Your code works correctly IF you modify an existing print are or add print area definition for a worksheet in the document that has got at least one print area already defined. It's probably because there are some other elements added when creating the first print area definition in a workbook. In orer to make it work, you should just use a template with one print area already defined. 
You also can remove localId and definedName from method's parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found some information about a method that seems not to be using Interop. You can try something like:

```
//load the work book
...

myWorkBook.Worksheets.First().PageSetup.PrintAreas.Add("A1:F40");

//save the workbook
//...
```

See if this helps. I haven't tried it myself yet, but I'm going to verify it.

**UPDATE:**
The first method seems to require an additional library. You can get it from here:
http://closedxml.codeplex.com/. I haven't used it myself, so I cannot assure you it works correctly.

**Pure OpenXML solution**

I've managed to change the print area by manually modifying the xlsx file contents in notepad editor.

In C# you should try to use the follwoing method (it sets printing area to *A1:G19*):

```
//first you need to get reference to your workbook, but I assume you already have this
//...
//then you can add an information about desired print area
DefinedNames definedNames = new DefinedNames();
DefinedName printAreaDefName = new DefinedName() { Name = "_xlnm.Print_Area", LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)0U };
printAreaDefName.Text = "Worksheet1!$A$1:$G$19";
definedNames.Append(printAreaDefName);
//then you should append the created element to your workbook
//...
workbook1.Append(definedNames);
```

The thing you need to change is line: `printAreaDefName.Text = "Worksheet1!$A$1:$G$19";`.

You should change the Text value to contain information in format: **[worksheet_name]![top-left corner of print area]:[bottom-right corner of print area]**. It should set your print area to a rectangle with upper-left and bottom-right corners as specified.

If you want to specify print areas for different worksheets, try to add multiple `DefinedName` objects:

```
  DefinedName printAreaDefName = new DefinedName() { Name = "_xlnm.Print_Area", LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)0U };
  printAreaDefName.Text = "Worksheet1!$A$1:$G$19";
  definedNames.Append(printAreaDefName);
  DefinedName printAreaDefName2 = new DefinedName() { Name = "_xlnm.Print_Area", LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)1U };
  printAreaDefName2.Text = "Worksheet2!$B$1:$H$23";
  definedNames.Append(printAreaDefName2);
  DefinedName printAreaDefName3 = new DefinedName() { Name = "_xlnm.Print_Area", LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)2U };
  printAreaDefName3.Text = "Worksheet3!$A$1:$J$10";
  definedNames.Append(printAreaDefName3);
```

I also recommend using **OpenXML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool**. It allows you to show the contents of a chosen OpenXML file, compare files, validate a file and even show a C# code that you would write in order to recreate the file programatically :).
You can download it from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124

**UPDATE II:**

I've corrected a mistake in format of the print area value string. Sorry for the confusion.
I've also took the code you posted and created a method based on it. It works correctly and after modifying the print area I can open the file in Excel without issues. The code assumes that a print range is already defined and you are now just changing it, but it can be modified to add new print range as well.
Here's the code:

```
private void OpenXmlFileHandling(String fileName)
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true))
        {
            //some sample values
            String definedName = "Worksheet3";
            String topLeft = "$A$3";
            String bottomRight = "$D$7";

            WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;

            var definedNames = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<DefinedNames>().FirstOrDefault();
            var namesCollection = definedNames.Descendants<DefinedName>().Where(m => m.Text.StartsWith(definedName));
            DefinedName name = namesCollection != null ? namesCollection.First() : null;

            UInt32Value locSheetId;
            //we assume that name is not null, because print range for this worksheet was defined in the source template file
            //if name was null, we should probably just assign to locSheetId a number definedNames.Count() + 1 and not remove the name node
            locSheetId = name.LocalSheetId;
            name.Remove();

            wbPart.Workbook.Save();
            name = new DefinedName() { Name = "_xlnm.Print_Area", LocalSheetId = locSheetId, Text = String.Format("{0}!{1}:{2}", definedName, topLeft, bottomRight) };


            definedNames.Append(name);

            wbPart.Workbook.Save();
        }
    }
```

I put the values of worksheet name and print area range inside the method, so you can see what kind of values they should have. I hope this helps.

Comment: This actually looks promising. I'll keep you posted..Thanks

Comment: Note about update: How does this change or set the PrintArea?

Comment: I think I've found how it's done now,but tell me do you need to set always the same print area or decide what it is dynamically.

Comment: I have to set it based on a template worksheet. (ie. Determine print area from template, and set it x number of times for each worksheet I copy over from the template.

Comment: Thanks Lucas! Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: One more thing.  From the above code it looks like the print area is worksheet specific.  I don't want to necessary specify a print area for a specific worksheet, but set a print area that spans across many worksheets in a workbook.  So if I have a workbook with 10 worksheets, a print should print every worksheet with the same defined range.  So, if I remove the specific worksheet name, and just have a range (A1:C50), will the perform as desired?

Comment: Keep getting corrupt data as well!?!?!? Frustrating for such a simple task.

Comment: Updated the answer to show an example for multiple worksheets.

Comment: I've corrected the format of text you should insert. It should be in i.e. Worksheet1!$A:$10.

Comment: Did you see my update? I have no idea why I get the error when I open in excel.  I open with the OpenXml Validator Tool, and there are no validation errors, but opening excel, gives me an unreadable content error

Comment: I saw it and updated this answer with it. I took your code and modified it to get a method posted in the answer. Take a look at the part code snippet and correct your code based on it. Read UPDATE II section.

Comment: when you set the localsheetid, that will fail if name is null.  thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, the code works if you defined the print area in the template before and are now just changing it to another value.

Comment: This is where I have a problem I think.  I am using a template with only one sheet, and one print area.  I am then copying that sheet into another workbook x times, and adding the print area to the new sheets without it already existing...

Comment: I suggest you to add the DefinedName nodes subtree if it's missing. Calculate all DefinedName nodes already existing, add 1 and assign this value to locSheetId. This should do the job. But first make sure it works if printarea is defined before if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain my case: I have excel workbook with following sheets (T1,I1,M1). Now my requirement was based on some condition T1,I1,M1 will be copied to same excel workbook multiple times e.g. T2,I2,M2, T3,I3,M3 and so on. For me I2,M2 did not have any issues with Print area but for copied sheet T2,T3... had issue. since it had huge data. excel column goes upto "AG". So here is what i did in code

Once the new sheet is added to workbook

```
sheets.Append(copiedSheet);
```

first get the current sheet count

```
var count = sheets.Count();
```

Get the sheet count, this will be used in LocalsheetId as printarea setting.

Only for copied techical sheet the print area was not set properly. Hence need to be set correctly.

```
DefinedName printAreaDefName = new DefinedName() { Name = "_xlnm.Print_Area", LocalSheetId = Convert.ToUInt32(count) };
```

Be care full with defName.Text the format is 'T1'!$A$1:$AG$19

```
printAreaDefName.Text = "'" + copiedSheet.Name + "'!$A$1:$AG$22";

workbookPart.Workbook.DefinedNames.Append(printAreaDefName); 
workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
```

There was no need for me to add new Definedname in DefinedNames collection. So I just added to workbook definedNames collection and it worked.